# Why the type parameter Entry is hiding the type Map.Entry?

Tags: java, generics

Eclipse complains about this code with "*The type parameter Entry is hiding the type Map.Entry*":

```
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class Test {
     static abstract class EntryIterator<Entry<K, V>> implements Iterator<K, V> {
     }
}
```

I don't quite understand what the problem is here - the type in question *is* `java.util.Map.Entry`. How can that shadow itself? How am I supposed to declare the inner class to make it compile?

Comment: Eclipse should be complaining about more than just that since what you have there is a syntax error.

Comment: @arshajii It does, now that I closed an re-opened all windows. It did show only that message before. Actually I've had that problem for years, should have done that sooner - Eclipse sometimes even keeps showing an error after you corrected it until the source window is closed :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is this part of the declaration:

```
class EntryIterator<Entry<K, V>>
```

That's trying to declare a type *parameter* called `Entry<K, V>` (which isn't valid). You're then saying that the class *implements* `Iterator<K, V>`, which is also invalid as `Iterator` only has a single type parameter.

I suspect you actually mean:

```
class EntryIterator<K, V> implements Iterator<Entry<K, V>>
```

Comment: Oh, damn thats exactly the problem. Maybe its time for a break :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean

```
static abstract class EntryIterator<T extends Entry<?, ?>> implements Iterator<T>
```

This puts the constrain on the generic parameter T of EntryIterator such that it must be an Entry of something. You create an instance with

```
new EntryIteartor<Map.Entry<K, V>>(...);
```